# Trying to display a Div when a list option with the word 'Yes' is selected - Woocommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-select2

I am trying to display a div depending on a specific word chosen in a list item created.

The code looks something like:

html (generated by select2 which replaces select/option through the theme with a list item):

```
<ul class="select2-results__options">
    <li class="select2-results__option">None</li>
    <li class="select2-results__option">Yes</li>
</ul>

<div class="wc-dnd-file-upload">...</div>
```

js:

```
jQuery(document).on("change", ".select2", function() {
if($(this).val() == 'Yes')
    $(".wc-dnd-file-upload").css("display", "block");
else
    $(".wc-dnd-file-upload").css("display", "none");
})
```

At the moment I am using a value to find 'Yes' which I realised won't work as the select2 dropdown box doesn't load until clicked. Assuming my code is correct this seems to be the cause to my issue.

All I want to do is target 'Yes' as text then show a div that is hidden by css.

Example of code that generates dropdown list in Woocommerce:

[image: code that generates dropdown]

Example of div I want to hide until 'Yes' is selected

[image]

Example of what I am trying to achieve when 'Yes' is selected in dropdown:

[image: result after 'Yes' is chosen]

Any help is much appreciated.

I have edited my question to show an image and amended the code to reflect Swati's answer.

Comment: Hi, you mean like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zepjfs2r/) ?

Comment: This is what I am looking for thanks! I can see I was completely out of sync with how I approached the issue. I will take your resolution on board and learn from this.

Comment: Edit: Sorry I have seen where my error is and to why I might have caused some confusion. I am trying to target a value that doesn't exist. My original code doesn't have a value and seeing that I am trying to look for one through jQuery wont work.

I just need to look for the text inside the list item. This is the issue I am facing with using select2 as a dropdown. The theme isn't built to be friendly.

Just to add - select2 is a jQuery function that replaces the standard select/option used in drop downs with a fancy one that can be styled.

Comment: Even with `value=""` it will work . Can you show your select-box ?

Comment: Hi @Swati I have updated my original question with screenshots and code from your example, with my changes to try and get it working.

Comment: They are dynamically generated and only shows in dom when user click on select2 else they don't exist . I am not getting why not use change on select-box itself ? `$(this).val()` will give you correct value .

Comment: Hi @Swati I can't understand myself to why it won't work. Everything looks as it should based on your example, the only difference is the class names. I am looking for the class **select2-results__option** and asking it do hide the class **wc-dnd-file-upload** until the value of **'Yes'** is selected.

The only difference is the div that I want to hide doesn't sit inside the same container (**wc-dnd-file-upload**). Would this make a difference?

Comment: Hi `select2-results__option`  only exist in dom when you click on select2 .

Comment: Hi, Ok this makes sense I think from looking at its element when clicked. If it's called into DOM when selected how do I listen for this in jQuery? I can get the div to hide but nothing happens on the value 'Yes'. I cant see anyone else on here asking a similar question. Most are related to adding to the list item itself. It could be looking ta me in the face but i cant get my head around it.

Comment: That option must be there inside your select-box . If there is different value here `value=""` you can compare with `text` of option tag . Here , is working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/bo6q8kLz/).